# St. Thomas Aquinas on the Question: "What Must I Do to Go to Heaven?''

Tags: catholicism, heaven, reference-request, thomas-aquinas

There is a story that relates to St. Thomas Aquinas and the question of "What must I do to go to Heaven" that I thought was somewhat famous, but I can't seem to locate it.

As I recall, the Mother Superior of a particular Order of nuns approached St. Thomas Aquinas and posed the aforementioned question. She also had with her a very fancy book with blank vellum pages made by the nuns in which St. Thomas was to record all the rules that they must follow in order top be assured of Heaven.

St. Thomas agreed.

However, when the book was returned to the nuns with all the necessary directives for them to follow in order to get to Heaven, it contained but the words, "Will it!"

**Can anyone tell me where I may find this story?** I would like to reference it.

Comment: I am not a Catholic but even I am aware that Thomas Aquinas  was dedicated and pious. I understand the validity of the story isn't part of the question, it is the source of the story and who might have produced it. I think it is worth pointing out that  personally not at all sure the purported answer was in keeping with his character.

Comment: @M__ Please see answer below.

Comment: Thanks @ProsperdesGarets thats useful .. "Do not judge others" and maybe I did.

Answer (score 3):

The following is extracted from the *Afterword* of Milton Lomask's short biography of the Cure of Ars:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I sought.